# Clean up a Fresh Install of Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: system-installation

I need to install Ubuntu just for minor development etc.

But lately ... I have come to notice plenty of ads and extra softwares on the installation. The Amazon stuff. All the extra little applications.
Like...

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```

I wish to have a more minimal kind of Ubuntu. A chosen few internet applications, development tools, etc. **Anyone have a list of things they purge from a fresh install of Ubuntu each time?**

(I thought of Lubuntu/XUbuntu but that is a tad TOO spartan. 
And also I need that GUI for connecting the Wireless internet devices (like a 3G/4G dongle) that comes in Ubuntu pre-installed (**Can I get that somewhere? Seperately?**)

Comment: "I need that GUI for connecting the Wireless internet devices (like a 3G/4G dongle) that comes in Ubuntu pre-installed" Gnome network manager is used in Ubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu.

Comment: This question may be a bit too open for SE, since every user will have his/her own needs and can customize the desktop in consequence. There is no single "correct" answer that we can agree on.

Comment: Don't ask two question in one question. Please split your problems into two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Modem Manager GUI from the Ubuntu software center to manage your 3G dongle.

Also, you can try the Ubuntu minimal CD install detailed here: [Minimal Install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)